# Laravel route using incorrect controller

Tags: php, regex, laravel, laravel-5

```
Route::get('/', 'CategoryController@index');
Route::get('wiki/{category_slug}', 'CategoryController@categoryIndex');
Route::get('wiki/{category_slug}/{article_slug}', 'ArticleController@show');
Route::resource('wiki/article', 'ArticleController');
```

When I try to access `wiki/article/create`, I get this error message: `Trying to get property of non-object` and it seems to be using the 3rd route `at ArticleController->show('article', 'create')`.

Does/what constraints does it need on the 3rd route (and 2nd since `wiki/article` for storing would not use the right controller either)?

Comment: How is this regex related ?

Comment: Please show `ArticleController` code.

Comment: @ThomasAyoub well I thought you needed to add a constraint (which is regex) to the route to exclude the word `article` from `{category}` so that it can go to the correct route

Comment: `->where('category_slug', '(?!article)([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)')` adding this seems to fix the issue, it won't use the 2nd or 3rd route when visiting `wiki/article`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you try  http://domain.com/wiki/article/create, your code is looking your routes and finding that:

```
Route::get('wiki/{category_slug}/{article_slug}','ArticleController@show');
```

Is what you are asking for, as {category_slug} and {article_slug} have no constrains and can be anything, including "article" and "create".

Try changing this route address:

```
    Route::get('wiki/category/{category_slug}', 'CategoryController@categoryIndex');
    Route::get('wiki/category/{category_slug}/article/{article_slug}', 'ArticleController@show');
```

That way you will have unique routes for different controllers.

If you really want to use the address you can add a regex constrain to the word 'article', like this:

```
    Route::get('wiki/{category_slug}', 'CategoryController@categoryIndex')->where(['category_slug'=>'\b(?:(?!article)\w)+\b']);
    Route::get('wiki/{category_slug}/{article_slug}', 'ArticleController@show')->where(['category_slug'=>'\b(?:(?!article)\w)+\b']);
```

Comment: That will work nicely, but it adds extra clutter to the URI - is there any way to exclude the word `article` with a regex constraint so the route doesn't try to find the category called "article"?

Comment: Thanks! Works well